# Get dates given a start date an end date and day of week

Tags: c#, datetime

Given a start date (DateTime), an end date (DateTime) and a list of DayOfWeek(s). How to get all the matching dates :

Example :

```
StartDate : "06/17/2016" 
EndDate : "06/30/2016" 
DayOfWeek(s) : [0(Monday), 1(Tuesday), 4(Friday)]
```

The wanted result is :

```
Dates = ["06/17/2016", "06/20/2016", "06/21/2016", "06/24/2016", "06/27/2016", "06/28/2016"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How about simply iterating through the dates and check if the `DayOfWeek` is in your criteria list?

Comment: Your date list seems a bit wrong... You are missing 2016-06-17 which is a friday and your start date (should they be exclusive?) and you are including 2016-06-29 which is a wednesday. Though it does show why you need this code to work it out for you it might be worth correcting this to avoid any confusion and to make it easy to confirm that the results from answers match the correct expected results. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return you list of all dates between the startDate and EndDate, that belong to the given enum of dayOfWeek:

```
var allDays = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days + 1).Select(d => startDate.AddDays(d));
var Dates = allDays.Where(dt => dayOfWeek.Contains(dt.DayOfWeek)).ToList();
```

Comment: Does `Enum.IsDefined(dayOfWeek, dt.DayOfWeek)` do what you think it does? the first argument is the type of an enum and it simply works out if that value is valid for the enum (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx). I think you just want something like `inputDaysOfWeek.Contains(dt.DayOfWeek)`. where `inputDaysOfWeek` is `IEnumerable<DayOfWeek>`

Comment: Needed to write typeOf and it works now. Thanks for pointing that out Chris. And I am assuming `dayOfWeek(s) : [0(Monday), 1(Tuesday), 4(Friday)]` is an enum. If it is just any list or collection, then I agree it should be `daysOfWeek.Contains(dt.DayOfWeek)`. I first answered that only but changed later seeing the code in the Question above. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Are you suggesting that the OP should define a new enum, putting in the values that are wanted and then checking that new enum for whether it contains a matching value from another enum? If so this sounds like a terrible idea!

Comment: If so, I've edited it assuming that dayOfWeek is a collection. Thanks for your helpful advice.

Comment: Much better. The problem with enum is that they are compile time constructs which would massively limit reusability if you were limited only to the sets of days that had been made into something like this. For example also you wouldn't be able to get the user to select the days they want on a form or similar.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

yet another possible solution, I think this is simple to understand and debug, even if it cost more lines and maybe little more resources than other possible solutions:

```
    var startDate = new DateTime(2016, 06, 17);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2016, 06, 30);

    DayOfWeek[] daysOfWeek = { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Friday };

    List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
    if (endDate >= startDate)
    {
        var tmp = startDate;
        tmp = tmp.AddDays(1); //I notice you didn't add 06/17/2016 that is friday, if you want to add it, just remove this line
        do
        {
            if (daysOfWeek.Contains(tmp.DayOfWeek))
                dates.Add(tmp);
            tmp = tmp.AddDays(1);
        }
        while (tmp <= endDate); //If you don't want to consider endDate just change this line into while (tmp < endDate); 
    }
```